# Lua pass table to function, modify it and get it back in C++

Tags: c++, struct, lua, lua-table, lua-api

I'm trying to add functionality in my program where I pass a C++ struct into Lua function let it play with it and then set it back to C++ program.

Lua function:

```
function test( arg )
    arg.var1 = arg.var1 * 2
    arg.var2 = 1
end
```

C++ function:

```
struct MyStruct
{
    int var1;
    int var2;
};

MyStruct arg;

arg.var1 = 2;
arg.var2 = 2;

lua_getglobal( L, "test" );

lua_newtable( L );

lua_pushstring( L, "var1" );
lua_pushinteger( L, arg.var1 );
lua_settable( L, -3 );

lua_pushstring( L, "var2" );
lua_pushinteger( L, arg.var2 );
lua_settable( L, -3 );

lua_pcall( L, 1, 0, 0 );

// now i want somehow to grab back the modified table i pushed to c++ function as arg
arg.var1 = lua_*
arg.var2 = lua_*
```

so that I end up with this:

```
arg.var1 == 4
arg.var2 == 1
```

But I have no idea how I could do this, is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two ways:

1. Make `test` return `arg`. In this case, use `lua_pcall( L, 1, 0, 1 )`.
2. Duplicate `arg` on the stack before calling `test` by adding these lines before `lua_pcall`:

--

```
lua_pushvalue( L, -1 );
lua_insert( L, -3 );
```

Either way, after `test` returns, you can get its fields with `lua_getfield`.

```
lua_getfield(L,-1,"var1")); arg.var1 = lua_tointeger(L,-1);
lua_getfield(L,-2,"var2")); arg.var2 = lua_tointeger(L,-1);
```

Comment: what i have to pass to getfield and getinteger to get the values with second solution?

Comment: Alternatively, make it a lua global via lua_setglobal.  I'm pretty sure there's an API for C code to have "hidden" globals, but I can't find it now.